# Rails & Sidekiq: Confused about Debounce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, debouncing

I'm building a Tinder style app where users can swipe through events.

Currently, I have a background job that is being fired any time a user swipes an event. With users swiping through 20 events per minute, I'm creating a ton of background jobs:

worker.rb

```
class Worker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(user_id, newly_voted_event_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    event = Event.find(newly_voted_event_id)
    events_to_rerank = event.similar.unvoted(user_id)
    events_to_rerank.each do |e|
      e.rank(user_id)
    end
  end    
end
```

user.rb:

```
def recalculate_similar_events(event_id)
  CalculateRelevantEventRankingsForUser.perform_async(self.id, event_id)
end
```

What I would like to do is run a maximum of one background job every 5 minutes per user. So I will use `sidekiq-debounce` change my background job to:

```
def recalculate_similar_events(event_id)
  CalculateRelevantEventRankingsForUser.perform_in(5.minutes, self.id, event_id)
end
```

I'm confused about what the gem does. Does it automatically execute all the jobs as one job in 5 minutes or does it just execute the first job in each 5 minute window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always in questions like this one if you not sure simplest way to figure out is to [look into gem code](https://github.com/hummingbird-me/sidekiq-debounce/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/debounce.rb#L16-L18):

```
    # Reschedule the old job to when this new job is scheduled for
    # Or yield if there isn't one scheduled yet
    jid = scheduled_jid ? reschedule(scheduled_jid, @msg['at']) : yield
```

so if one job is already here when you call for another run, it'll be rescheduled to 5 minutes later.

**Update:** 
As it seems from comments you looking for [sidekiq-rate-limiter](https://github.com/enova/sidekiq-rate-limiter) not debounce.

Comment: Basically my goal is to cut down on the number of background jobs. Let's say I currently have 1 job running every minute for 5 minutes. Without debouncing it would be running 5 jobs (every 60 seconds). *With* debouncing, would it also be running 5 jobs (every 5 minutes)? OR would it run 1 job (every 5 minutes, combining 5 jobs into 1)?

Comment: Look at this code. With conditions defined there will be 0 jobs running. Because on every call, it'll be rescheduled on +5 minutes from now. So it'll run for the first time only when next call will happen on +5.01.