# Rails: How to add Sidekiq::Debounce to my middleware chain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, debouncing

I am using [Sidekiq debounce](https://github.com/hummingbird-me/sidekiq-debounce) to rate limit the number of jobs in a timeframe. Here's my job:

```
class CalculateAllEventRankingsForUser
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options debounce: true

  def perform(user_id)
    puts "recalculating all events for user"
    ## do some work
  end

end
```

Where I call the job:

```
CalculateAllEventRankingsForUser.perform_in(20.seconds, self.id)
```

And my sidekiq initializer:

```
 Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.client_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Debounce
  end
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Debounce
  end
end
```

The issue is that all my sidekiq jobs are still being processed, even if I fire multiple within the 20 second time frame. My intention is for only one job to be fired every 20 seconds (maximum).

From the docs:

> Add Sidekiq::Debounce to your client middleware chain, and then add
>   sidekiq_options debounce: true to the worker you wish to debounce.
>
> Use #perform_in instead of #perform_async to set the timeframe.

The main thing I'm not sure about is how to add Sidekiq::Debounce to my middleware chain. Not sure if I'm doing that right.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: You keep asking same question instead of reading previous answer on your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119004/rails-sidekiq-confused-about-debounce/40119327?noredirect=1#comment67509958_40119327

Comment: Hey @SergeyMoiseev. I implemented your solution from previous answer. This is a different question with more specific details. I rewrote my code so that debounce is the ideal solution. But I am unsure of how to add Sidekiq::Debounce to my middleware chain.. Right now, I am trying to implement sidekiq-debounce but all my jobs are still firing.

Comment: Which version of siqekiq do you use?

Comment: sidekiq (4.2.3)
sidekiq-debounce (1.1.0)

Comment: It's incompatible: https://github.com/hummingbird-me/sidekiq-debounce/issues/10

Comment: Ah. So would you recommend using an earlier version of sidekiq or finding a different debounce gem?

Answer (score 0):

`sidekiq-debounce` works with sidekiq 4.2. The reason it didn't is likely caused by the way client middleware was configured in the code you've shared.

This should work:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Debounce
  end
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.client_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Debounce
  end
end
```